# BASH and/or .BASHRC not working properly after SU or SSH login unless run "bash" command

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I have an Amazon EC2 Machine running Ubuntu 10.04.

The default user, ubuntu's `.bashrc` seems to be behaving properly, but if I `ssh` or `su` to the second user, mikey, it doesn't display properly until I run `bash`:

Ex 1.) Changing user with `su`

```
mikey@home ~$ ssh ubuntu@EC2
ubuntu@EC2:~$
ubuntu@EC2:~$ su mikey
$ 
$ bash
mikey@EC2: $
```

Ex 2.) SSH-ing in directly as the user

```
mikey@home ~$ ssh mikey@EC2
/home/mikey/.bashrc: 13: shopt: not found
/home/mikey/.bashrc: 21: shopt: not found
/home/mikey/.bashrc: 99: shopt: not found
/etc/bash_completion: 33: [[: not found
/etc/bash_completion: 39: [[: not found
/etc/bash_completion: 52: Bad substitution
\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]\u@\h:\w$
\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]\u@\h:\w$ bash
mikey@EC2:~$
```

I've tried playing around with `~/.profile` and `~/.bash_login` to include

```
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
        . ~/.bashrc
fi
```

but so far, nothing has seemed to do the trick.

any pointers would be greatly appreciated. thanks!

Comment: Can you `echo $SHELL` from the non-working shell? It's possible (and likely, based on the lone `$`) that it's not `bash`.

Comment: Thanks, you're exactly correct.

\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]\u@\h:\w$ echo $SHELL
/bin/sh

Googling now to see how to change that, but any pointers would be appreciated. :)

Comment: See below for an example using `usermod`.

Comment: You're the man. Editing /etc/passwd to point the mikey user to /bin/bash seemed to do the trick.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

If, in fact, your shell isn't `bash`, you can try to change it like so:

```
usermod -s /bin/bash mikey
```

If /bin/bash is the location of `bash` on that system.

Answer (score 3):

I think your default shell is `dash` or `sh` and not `bash` in this case. `echo $SHELL` should show it, should it show `/bin/sh`, it might be a link, so check that `ls -l /bin/sh` doesn't link to some other shell.

Answer (score 2):

Can't you use `chsh` to change shell? instead of hacking /etc/passwd?

Answer (score 1):

In order to fix this on the permanent basis, change /etc/passwd

From:

**kwilson:x:3042:3042::/home/jjson:/bin/sh**

Change it to:

**kwilson:x:3042:3042::/home/jjson:/bin/bash**

Comment: You should use `chsh` or `usemod` for this.